# Prevent the use of a method in another method

Tags: typescript

I want to prevent the use of one method (`baz`) in another method (`bar`) with types alone, because this is undesirable for some reason, e.g. causes infinite recursion. I would prefer to avoid runtime checks.

This works but requires to specify `this` in implementation, a developer who writes `Foo` should be aware of the restriction:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstract bar(): void;

    baz() {
        this.bar();
    }
} 

class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    bar<T extends this & { baz: never }>(this: T) {
        this.baz(); // restriction exists here
    }
}
```

I would like to infer `this` that restricts the use of `baz` in `bar`, this doesn't work:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstract bar<T extends this & { baz: never }>(this: T): void;

    baz() {
        (this as any).bar(); // restriction exists here
    }
} 

class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
    bar() {
        this.baz(); // restriction doesn't exist here
    }
}
```

The objective is to notify a developer who isn't aware of the restriction with type check, so snippet 1 isn't a good option.

Can this restriction be imposed with inheritance or in some other way that wouldn't require to specify `this` type in `Foo` implementation?

If there are blocking TypeScript issues that can be tracked for progress, references are welcome.

Comment: it really sounds like you should refactor your code for the infinite recursion to not happen rather than trying to stop others from calling the methods.

Comment: Don't think this is possible unless you are willing to create `Foo` using a HOC. The compiler will not check the type of `this` against the base class if there is no explicit annotation

Comment: @toskv Class design is correct, so refactoring is not an option. One of these methods is a hook that is supposed to be triggered by another one. Recursion was given only as an example, but calling `baz` is never desirable in `bar`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I suspected that this is impossible. Can you give an example for a HOC? Could be a workaround.

Comment: @estus Added a workaround .. let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the original `AbstractFoo` and only expose a function to allow extension of `AbstarctFoo` you can use a bit of conditional types to get an error if `this` is not specified on bar:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    abstract bar<T extends this & { baz: never }>(this: T): void;

    baz() {
        (this as any).bar(); // restriction exists here
    }
} 

type ValidateThisOfBar<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = InstanceType<T> extends  { bar(this: infer TThis): void } ? 
    TThis extends {baz: never} ? T: "method bar does not have this defined": never;

export function createFoo<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(creator : (base: typeof AbstractFoo) => T & ValidateThisOfBar<T>): ValidateThisOfBar<T> {
    return creator(AbstractFoo) as any;
}

const Foo  = createFoo(b => class extends b { // Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type '"method bar does not have this defined"'.
    bar() {
        this.baz(); 
    }
});
type Foo = InstanceType<typeof Foo>
new Foo() // error Foo is never

const Foo2  = createFoo(b => class extends b {
    bar<T extends this & { baz: never }>(this: T) {
        this.baz(); // error here
    }
});
type Foo2 = InstanceType<typeof Foo>
```

This does not solve the problem for classes derived from `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about providing a factory for convenience, this is a good argument for that.